# Angular Select. Add element and automatically select it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Look ex. [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/molo4nik11/5HJU8/)

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mCtrl">
    <select size="20" ng-model="selectedType" ng-init="selectedType=types[0]" 
    ng-options="type.name for type in types">

    </select>
    <button ng-click="addElem()">add elem in array</button>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.types = [ my Array of objects ];

$scope.addElem = function() {
    element = {
        "id": 999,
        "name": "xxx"
    };
    $scope.types.push(element);
}
```

I want to add element in ng-options array, and automatically select it in select Box with model changing. 
I tried

```
$scope.selectedType = $scope.types[$scope.types.lenght - 1]
```

, but it doesn't work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo! minor mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misspelled `length`.

Here is solution which works:

```
app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.types = [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Zaj"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Emoltra"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Malathion"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Pyramax"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Boink"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Savvy"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Accruex"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Zappix"
    }
];
    $scope.addElem = function() {
        element = {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Zappix"
        };
        $scope.types.push(element);
        $scope.selectedType = $scope.types[$scope.types.length - 1];

    }


})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5HJU8/3/)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there is a typo you have misspelled `length`

```
$scope.selectedType = $scope.types[$scope.types.length- 1]
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5HJU8/4/)

***OR***

You can set it using `$scope.selectedType = element`

```
$scope.addElem = function () {
    element = {
        "id": $scope.types.length + 1,
            "name": "Zappix" + $scope.types.length + 1
    };
    $scope.types.push(element);
    $scope.selectedType = element;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5HJU8/3/)